# Why are my imports no longer working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, wtforms

I refactored my webapp and now my IDE pycharm marks some imports red. Why?

`from wtforms import Form, TextField, validators, SelectField`

My IDE marks the `Form`, `TextField` and the `SelectField` red as they cannot be imported. ("Unresolved reference"). What should I do if I need those classes in my project?

Comment: Did you choose your env in pycharm? are you sure wtforms installed?

Comment: @OrDuan I did not install wtforms to python, I just keep the library alongside my other dependencies. I suppose I should install it to python with pip or similar? Or add it with my env in pycharm if I knew how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install it in in your environment(according to the comments you didn't), please try the following:

Settings -> Project: MyProjectName -> Project Interpreter

Then click on the green plus and choose your packages

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting the libraries from your project if they are in libraries, then re-importing those libraries.

Also, I assume you've done this, but make sure the libraries are actually installed and present in a reachable location that is properly mapped.